# React Native debug menu is not appearing in Xiaomi Redmi 3S when send 82 keyevent

Tags: android, react-native, xiaomi

I am following react native developer guid. There is paragraph where it tells that if you want to enable *Live Reloading*/*How Reloading* you can do `adb shell input keyevent 82`. It works perfectly with emulators. But when I do the same with my android device it shows me screen with my activity history instead of developer menu. I permit "Display pop-up window" and tuned off the "Tun on MIUI optimization".
Is there some workaround?

Thanks

Comment: the problem still exists. any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of your device, there are 3 buttons: menu button, home button, and back button.

Long press on menu button will show the Developer Menu.